# Generating a specified amount of random numbers

Tags: java, random

Okay, so I have a method that prints one random number

public void printOneRandomNumber()
    {

```
    System.out.println(x.nextInt());
}
```

How do I make the same sort of method that would take in an int parameter specifying how many random numbers to print. For example, passing in 10 would print 10 random numbers. I am not trying to specify the range that the random number should be generated in, just the amount of them.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially do exactly what you are doing for one random number but within the following for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRandomNumbers; i ++){
// Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to [declare parameters for a function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and how to do [for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Your code would look something like this:

```
public void printRandomNumbers(int numRandoms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numRandoms; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(x.netInt());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
        System.out.println(x.nextInt());
```

This should do it. A "for" loop can be used for repetitive tasks.